# Unity3D - How to get highest value for acceleration from Input.gyro

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, accelerometer, gyroscope

I'm trying to develop an app that can detect car acceleration, braking and cornering speed. I need to detect device acceleration. Is that acceleration high or low?. Like flo app on Google Play.

I'm using gyroscope and I need to get highest value for user acceleration (x, y, z axises) from gyroscope. Values of x, y and z are changing every frame. I need to achieve highest value of this 3 axis for later use.

Now my current code looks like this

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
 public Text x, y, z;

 void Start()
 {
     Input.gyro.enabled = true;
 }

 void Update()
 {
     x.text = Mathf.Abs(Input.gyro.userAcceleration.x).ToString();
     y.text = Mathf.Abs(Input.gyro.userAcceleration.y).ToString();
     z.text = Mathf.Abs(Input.gyro.userAcceleration.z).ToString();
 }
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: your question is confusing.... you want to check which axis is greater than 3 of them? Explain more about what you are trying to do...

Comment: No. I want to get highest value for each axis

Comment: get the highest value of x,y,z...that doesn't make sense. If you really need help, modify your question and add what you mean by highest value and  what you are trying to archive.

Comment: values of x ,y and z are changing every frame. I need to achieve highest value of this 3 axis for later use

Comment: Ok. To make it clear, you want to get the highest value of each axis every 1 second?

Comment: Yes. You are right

Comment: Ok. I will be back. Please modify your question to reflect this.

Comment: Check my answer. I wasn't able to test it because Unity wouldn't detect my phone so let me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Time.deltaTime;` to do a timer then store `Input.gyro.userAcceleration` to a temporary `Vector3` variable and **compare** it later on with a new value from the Gyro in the next frame. If the new value is `>` the old `vector3` value, **overwrite** the old value. When timer is up, you can use the old values as the highest values.

```
 void Start()
 {
     Input.gyro.enabled = true;
 }

bool firstRun = true;
float counter = 0;
float calcTime = 1; //Find highest gyro value  every 1 seconds
Vector3 oldGyroValue = Vector3.zero;
Vector3 highestGyroValue = Vector3.zero;

    void Update()
    {
        gyroFrame();
    }

    void gyroFrame()
    {

        if (firstRun)
        {
            firstRun = false; //Set to false so that this if statement wont run again
            oldGyroValue = Input.gyro.userAcceleration;
            counter += Time.deltaTime; //Increment the timer to reach calcTime
            return; //Exit if first run because there is no old value to compare with the new gyro value 
        }

        //Check if we have not reached the calcTime seconds 
        if (counter <= calcTime)
        {
            Vector3 tempVector = Input.gyro.userAcceleration;
            //Check if we have to Update X, Y, Z
            if (tempVector.x > oldGyroValue.x)
            {
                oldGyroValue.x = tempVector.x;
            }

            if (tempVector.y > oldGyroValue.y)
            {
                oldGyroValue.y = tempVector.y;
            }

            if (tempVector.z > oldGyroValue.z)
            {
                oldGyroValue.z = tempVector.z;
            }
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
        }

        //We have reached the end of timer. Reset counter then get the highest value
        else
        {
            counter = 0;
            highestGyroValue = oldGyroValue;
            Debug.Log("The Highest Values for X: " + highestGyroValue.x + "  Y: " + highestGyroValue.y +
                "  Z: " + highestGyroValue.z);
        }
    }
```